# Arraylist is suddenly considered empty

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

i'm tasked with writing a game of Blackjack, i created a class for the cards, which have a int variable with their value and a String with the color of the card (heart, club, diamond and spade). I organize the cards with a class "deck", which contains an ArrayList of all 52 Cards. When i want to give out a card i use the following code:

```
public Card give(){
    Card d = c.get(0); //c is the Arraylist
    c.remove(0);
    return d;
}
```

Since i have to use 6 decks i created another class named playdeck, which has an Array of 6 "deck" objects. here i simply use this code to obtain a card:

```
class playdeck{enter code here
static int x = 0;
static int y = 0;
static deck[] play = new deck[6];
public playdeck(){
    play[0] = new deck();
    play[1] = new deck();
    play[2] = new deck();
    play[3] = new deck();
    play[4] = new deck();
    play[5] = new deck();

}
public static Card give(){
    y++;
    if(y == 53){
    y = 0;
    x++;
    }
    Card d = play[x].give();
    return d;}
```

everything works fine for the first 2 decks, but as soon as the program tries to enter the third deck object and obtain a card, the following error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out-of-bounds for length 0 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64) at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70) at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:439)
    at deck.give(deck.java:39)
    at playdeck.give(playdeck.java:23)
    at Blackjack.main(Blackjack.java:5)
```

when i try to access the third "deck" object, everything works fine, as well as all the other "deck" objects, but as soon as i try to give out more then 2 packs of cards, the program crashes. Has anybody any tipp as to why this happens? here"s my main method btw:

```
public static void main (String[] args){
playdeck blackjack = new playdeck();
for (int x = 0; x < 312; x++){
System.out.println(blackjack.give().name);
}}
```

Comment: Why are you assigning elements of `play` in the constructor? This means you are going to overwrite elements of `play` every time you create an instance of `playdeck`. Either `play` shouldn't be static, or you should be using a static initializer instead of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that it's required to remove card from `ArrayList` every time when you need it? Because you can do the follow:

   ```
   static int i = 0;

   public Card give() {
       return c.get(i++);
   }
   ```

   Even if it's required to remove objects from `ArrayList`, then replace

   ```
   public Card give(){
       Card d = c.get(0); //c is the Arraylist
       c.remove(0);
       return d;
   }
   ```

   with

   ```
   public Card give(){
       return c.remove(0);
   }
   ```

   Explanation here: [ArrayList remove docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(int))
2. Error is here:

   ```
   public static Card give(){
       y++;
       if(y == 53){
           y = 0;
           x++;
       }
   Card d = play[x].give();
   return d;
   }
   ```

   Because you handle only first deck of cards correctly, and forget about others. This code will solve your problem:

   ```
   static int i = 0;

   public static Card give() {
       i++;
       y = i % 52; //0-51
       x = i / 52; //0-5
       return play[x].give();
   }
   ```
3. And please, take a look at the [Java coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)